# What are `styles.css.less` and `styles.css.scss` files

Tags: css, angular, webpack, sass, less

I'm going through webpack configuration of the angular-cli and have found the following rules for css related loaders:

```
{
    "include": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
    ],
    "test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
    "use": [...]
},
{
    "include": [
        path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
    ],
    "test": /\.less$/,
    "use": [...]
}
```

If my understanding correct these should match the following files `styles.css.less` and `styles.css.scss`. What kind of files are these or am I missing something?

**I know what sass and less files are.** But I've never seen the extension being `css.less` or `css.scss` yet it seems that this is exactly what the extension should be for the loader to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")` comes from `styles` section of `.angular-cli.json` file.

Angular-cli offers you 4 options for building css

1) css

```
"include": [
  path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
],
"test": /\.css$/,
```

2) sass

```
"include": [
  path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
],
"test": /\.scss$|\.sass$/,
```

3) less

```
"include": [
  path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
],
"test": /\.less$/,
```

4) stylus

```
"include": [
  path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css")
],
"test": /\.styl$/,
```

You can add desired style file to json

```
"styles": [
   "styles.css",
   "main.less",
   "common.styl"
],
```

and all these files will fall into the `include` section of your `webpack.config`(if you didn't run `ng eject` otherwise you have to add it yourself)

```
"include": [
  path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\styles.css"),
  path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\main.less"),
  path.join(process.cwd(), "src\\common.styl")
],
```

but loader will process only dedicated for loader exstension.